# ADT is not working with the cordova3.5.1

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an app using cordova 3.5.0 by using android-4.4.2 with an api level 19.
It was working fine till morning but suddenly i am getting the following error,
I know that the cordova 3.5.1 got released. I did not update my cordova version also and i have checked the version which is still 3.5.0.

Can any body have any idea regarding this error?

```
D:\ClonedMobWorkspace\mobiledev>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run "android" from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
at C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:80:29
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
at C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
at flush (C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: C:\Users\Admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

If you see error above some how it is downloading 3.5.1 when adding the android platform even i installed 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
Error: Please install Android target 19 (the Android newest SDK). 
Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well.
```

Check your Android SKD manager if there are any updates.

Run `android` from your command line (navigate to your Android SDK folder in case it's not in your path) or execute `SDK Manager`.

There might be a new revisions for API19 and/or Android SDK Tools you have not yet installed.

Comment: Thank you @benka, I have checked already, every thing was fine. still it is getting problem

Comment: Please observe the error in my post, It is showing 3.5.1 cordova but i installed 3.5.0